# Smooth scrolling anchors affecting bootstrap carousel arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've always used this script (found in CSS Tricks I think) to make smooth scrolling anchor links:

```
$(function() {
 $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
 if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') === this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname === this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
}
  });
});
```

It works like a charm! However, I just noticed that this scripts conflicts with how the Twitter Bootstrap carousel arrows work (since it uses anchors as well)

```
        <a data-slide="prev" href="#mySlideshow" class="left carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a data-slide="next" href="#mySlideshow" class="right carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
```

I would like to know if there's a way I could modify the script to affect all anchor links BUT exclude the anchors inside any Bootstrap carousel.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try like this `$('a[href*="#"]:not(.carousel-control)')`

Answer (score 0):

just change `.not()` argument like `$('a[href*="#"]:not(.carousel-control)')`

Here is the full example of your code

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not(.carousel-control)').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Play here if you want https://jsfiddle.net/eqaxxq5n/1/

> But using like this `a[href*="#"]` might cause any issue again so it's better use any class or indicator to initialize your smooth effect like `a.smoothClass[href*="#"]` or something else.

Hope it make sense to you.